# Why did they meet the "ghost of Caesar" or go on the "road to Mandalay" in "Long Road out of Eden"?

Tags: song-lyrics, eagles

The lyrics to *Long Road out of Eden* by the Eagles are as follows:

> Moon shinin' down through the palms
>   Shadows movin' on the sand
>   Somebody whisperin' the twenty-third psalm
>   Dusty rifle in his tremblin' hands
>
> Somebody tryin' just to stay alive
>   He got promises to keep
>   Over the ocean in America
>   Far away and fast asleep
>
> Silent stars blinkin' in the blackness of an endless sky
>   Cold silver satellites, ghostly caravans passin' by
>   Galaxies unfoldin', new world's bein' born
>   Pilgrims and prodigals creepin' toward the dawn
>   And it's a long road out of Eden
>
> Music blastin' from an SUV
>   On a bright and sunny day
>   Rollin' down the Interstate
>   In the good old USA
>
> Havin' lunch at The Petroleum Club
>   Smokin' fine cigars and swappin' lives
>   He said, "Give me another slice of that barbecued brisket
>   Give me another piece of that pecan pie"
>
> Freeways flickerin', cell phones chimin' a tune
>   We're ridin' to utopia, road map says we'll be arrivin' soon
>   Captains of the old order clingin' to the reins
>   Assurin' us these aches inside are only growin' pains
>   But it's a long road out of Eden
>
> Back home, I was so certain the path was very clear
>   But now I have to wonder what are we doin' here'
>   I'm not countin' on tomorrow and I can't tell wrong from right
>   But I'd give anythin' to be there in your arms tonight
>
> Weavin' down the American highway
>   Through the litter and the wreckage and the cultural junk
>   Bloated with entitlement, loaded on propaganda
>   Now we're drivin' dazed and drunk
>
> Been down the road to Damascus, the road to Mandalay
>   Met the ghost of Caesar on the Appian Way
>   He said, "It's hard to stop this bingein' once you get a taste
>   But the road to empire is a bloody stupid waste"
>   Behold the bitten apple, the power of the tools
>   But all the knowledge in the world is of no use to fools
>   And it's a long road out of Eden

The Appian Way was a major Roman Road. The Road to Damascus was presumably referring to the Apostle Paul's conversion experience, and presumably the "bitten apple" is referring to the fall of Adam and Eve (hence the "long road out of Eden").

Was Caesar selected because he represented imperialist empire-building? If so, is this song primarily "about" imperialism and war, or is it talking about imperialism more in the context of overall American materialism and "cultural junk"?

One more factor to consider: the very next song is "I Dreamed There Was No War." I *highly* doubt that this placement was coincidental.

Also, what's the significance of Mandalay?

Comment: I think the bitten apple is *also* a reference to the logo of the Apple corporation.

Comment: I hesitate to chip in when I don't feel I can write a full answer, but the ghost of caesar is a reference to Brutus being warned of defeat in Shakespeare's Julius Caesar. For the road to Mandalay, see the Kipling poem 'Mandalay'.

Comment: Do you really need to quote the entire song here? Maybe quote the relevant portions, and provide a link to the fully lyrics?